# Whenever i add an event, it disables all my commands, why does it do this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever i add an event, it disables all my commands, why does it do this? This is my code that i have so far. Is it because i have ctx AND message written and they just dont work together or what? This is not all of my code, this is only the part where im having trouble. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()

    curseWord = ['badword', 'badword2']
    
    if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
      await message.delete()
      embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description="Hey! Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

keep_alive()

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I worked out this command myself today and one seeing it I got the issue.

When this on_message was called by you yourself whereas usually it is called by this couroutine itself. So as you called it yourself you need to do it again.

You need to add this statement:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I changed the code in accordance to your code and hope this helps.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()

    curseWord = ['badword', 'badword2']
    
    if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
      await message.delete()
      embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description="Hey! Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      await bot.process_commands(message)

keep_alive()

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

---

This would work for you. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: Hey so i tried this and it still does not work.

Comment: the commands still are disabled and the only thing that works is the event above.

Comment: I edited a little piece of code and added this line in an else statement. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks Dude! :D Appreciate it. Accept this answer if you got it working. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands
> from running. To fix this, add a bot.process_commands(message) line at
> the end of your on_message. For example:
>
> ```
> @bot.event 
> async def on_message(message):
>     # do some extra stuff here
>
>     await bot.process_commands(message)
> ```

---

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)